# How can I achieve this functionality with OOP?

Tags: php, oop

I'm wrapping my inferior mind around classes. It is struggling with it by looking at other peoples code and finding it hard to see how it relates to my own code. I am hoping you can help me see how it works by turning 2 simple functions I have into classes so that I can see a relatable example.

A simple couple of functions:

```
function make_url_friendly($string) {

  $remove = array(',',' ','?','=','&','-','|');
  $replace = array('_','_','_','_','','_','');

  $string = strtolower(str_replace($remove,$replace,$string));  
  return $string;

}

function save_page($url) {

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO pages 
        SET url="' . mysql_real_escape_string(make_url_friendly($url)) . '" ';
 mysql_query($sql);

}


save_page('/questions/ask');
```

What might be the oop equivalent to functions like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class URLHandler{

   // Class variables
   $url = "";

   // Constructors
   public URLHandler($newurl) {  // Old Style
      $this->__construct($newurl);
   }

   public __construct($newurl) {  // New Style
      $this->setUrl($newurl);
   }

   private function make_url_friendly($string) {
      $remove = array(',',' ','?','=');
      $string = strtolower(str_replace($remove,"_",$string));
      return $string;
   }

   public function save_page() {
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO pages 
        SET url="' . mysql_real_escape_string($this->url) . '" ';
      mysql_query($sql);

   }

   public function getUrl(){
      return $this->url;
   }
   public function setUrl($newurl){
      $this->url = $this->make_url_friendly($newurl);
   }
};


//save_page('/questions/ask');
$somevar = new URLHandler("/questions/ask");
$somevar->save_page();

$somevar->setUrl("/answers/answer");
$somevar->save_page();
```

***Edit:***

As Shef pointed out in the comments, you really want to group items of similar function into their own class. For example, all your function s which do something to the DB would have a class different than your functions which handle form error checking.

Therefore in your example `make_url_friendly` would be in a different class from `save_page`

Comment: `__construct` (double underscore). I think `save_page` should be in a different class, it's related pages, so it should be a function within  the class `Page`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of `__construct`, and I agree that `save_page` should be in a different class. I decided to go with a single class in this case to do a straight translation. I guess I should have added an explanation.

Comment: So is putting things in 'classes' is for organising and access? Although I don't really understand everything above its answered some things. I'm looking up the difference between private and public functions inside classes.

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to make such a bit of code in OOP-style.

You can disguise your code in OOP syntax like in the other answer, but there will be no OOP in real.

make_url_friendly() function is all right being a function.

As for the save_page() it could be a method of some class but nobody can say what class it could be as noone knows your setup

Comment: I see. Thanks for that Col. My setup is usually to have a bunch of functions like this in a functions.php file and I basically include this file on every page. It seems to do the job, and I don't really have a problem with this and I don't understand the limitations of it either. I seem to be able to use functions in other functions to avoid repetition. Still, I would like to learn OOP so I can understand what I'm missing out on.